# How to populate Firebase with data from a JSON file programmatically?

Tags: java, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that once in the Firebase console, one can use the "Import" function and upload a .json file with the required data.

In my case, I have a web page, which contains only the .json data. I want to download this web page and upload the data to Firebase. The upload process could be from a stand-alone computer application or from a JavaScript web page.

The idea is to let the owner of the data import the files into Firebase without any contact with Firebase's console.

Is such thing achievable? If yes, I would appreciate any pointers given.

Comment: If your security rules allow it, just read in the contents of the file as a json/map object and set it as the value of a node. If you need to bypass security rules check out the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Answer (score 3):

The [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) can be used to manipulate data for a Firebase project.

Install it with Node/NPM:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Sign in with your Google account:

```
firebase login
```

Select your Firebase project for the CLI to use:

```
firebase use --add
```

Finally, import your JSON files:

```
firebase database:set /dataDestination ./data.json
```

`database:set` will replace all data at the specified location (`/dataDestination` above). If you would rather push data to a list instead, use `database:push`.

You should be able to implement this programmatically through Bash or whatever scripting language you prefer that can access shell commands.

A more comprehensive guide and reference for the CLI can be found here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/